# Create filter in Gmail for forwarded emails

Tags: gmail

I have two Gmail accounts, one personal and one given by my university. I have set email forwarding so that all mails that come to my university address are forwarded to my personal account. I wish to create a filter so that all messages forwarded from my university address are moved to a separate folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select one of the forwarded ones, you should be able to click the more button and get the option to 'filter messages like these' then you can filter them on the to: field which would be your university address.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to filter by the from address, there are multiple choices here. See the [Gmail help page for creating rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en).

or

You can go back to the forward setup and add filter there. See the Lifewire article ["How to Forward Gmail Email Using Filters"](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-forward-gmail-email-using-filters-1171934).